# Persisting ZonedDateTime to mysql database using JPA

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-boot, java-8, java-time

I have a column `created_at` in `mysql` database with datatype `TIMESTAMP`. Through JPA, I was persisting a variable of type `java.uti.Calendar` to column `created_at`. Now I want to change the datatype from `Calendar` to `ZonedDateTime` and I did. When I save the java object to mysql database, it is throwing the error

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x0Djava.time.Ser\x95]\x84\xBA\x1B"H\xB2\x0C\x00\x00xpw\x15\x06\x00\x00\x07\xE1\x09\x0A\x0C\x109)l\xDB\xC0' for column 'u_created_at' at row 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3971)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2501)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
... 159 common frames omitted
```

How to solve this issue. I am thinking of converting `ZonedDateTime` back to `Calendar` and then save it. Will it work or is there a better way of doing.

Thank you

Comment: A MySQL imestamp doesn't contain any TimeZone information. So mapping a ZonedDateTime to a Timestamp doesn't make much sense: you will lose the TimeZone information. But anyway, you need to use the right hibernate version (or additional jar fle) in order to have java.time support in Hibernate. Read the hibernate documentation. Or at least tell which version you're using, and what you have done to make sre java.time support is enabled.

Comment: I am using `hibernate-jpa-2.1` and `hibernate-core-5.0.12` and `hibernate-validator-5.3.5`

Comment: Then also use https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-java8, or upgrade to the latest version, that has native support.

Comment: Then, what datatype in java should I use instead of `calendar`?

Comment: It depends on what the information actually represents. If TIMESTAMP is the right data type in the database, then you should probably use an Instant in the entity, i.e. a ZonedDateTime... without a Zone.

Comment: It worked, but I have a doubt. While debugging, `createdAt` had `UTC Time`, but in my `database` it is showing local time. why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154056/discussion-between-virat-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: Could that be a “feature” of your database or your query interface that it translates the timestamp to local time when displaying it? Just guessing.